# Use underscore.js to find an object in another object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#collections), what is the simplest way to get the **ID** of the object with the person named "Ted"?

**Example:**

```
var people = {
  1: { name: "Ted" },
  2: { name: "Will" },
  3: { name: "James" }
}
```

**Raw JS solution:**

```
var personId;

for (id in people) {
  if (people[id].name === "Ted") {
    personId = id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? There's a [section dedicated to objects](http://underscorejs.org/#objects).

Comment: There is but, I tried findKey and couldn't get the syntax to work

Comment: You are referring to "key" or "property name", not "ID". Also, minor point, but in your "raw JS" version you should break out of the loop once you've got a match.

Comment: @DonnyP Show us the syntax you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`findKey`](http://underscorejs.org/#findKey):

```
var personId = _.findKey(people, function(obj) { return obj.name === 'Ted' });
```

Blender suggests this simplified version:

```
var personId = _.findKey(people, { name: 'Ted' });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there are several id with the same name, I propose you a raw JS solution that gives you an object inside only remains properties matching :

```
var people = {
  1: { name: "Ted" },
  2: { name: "Will" },
  3: { name: "James" },
  4: { name: "Ted" }
};
var keys = Object.keys(people);
result = {};
keys.forEach(item => {if (people[item].name === "Ted")result[item] = {name: people[item].name}});
console.log(result); // { '1': { name: 'Ted' }, '4': { name: 'Ted' } }
```